# Is it more convenient to get to Heathrow via Reading than via central London?

Tags: trains, lhr, england

My family and I live in the South West of England. We have a flight from Heathrow in a few months time.

Rather than getting a train to central London and then getting the express from central London to Heathrow, which seems to be the default, I am thinking of getting a train to Reading and then take a taxi to Heathrow.

How does the latter option fare in terms of time and cost compared to the former?

Comment: when I go to LHR from Portsmouth, I take the train to Woking and then a bus. It's over an hour quicker than going to London and taking the Heathrow Express.

Comment: Why not take the Rail-Air coach from Reading to Heathrow? Much cheaper than a taxi!

Comment: Interesting that there's a proposal for a direct rail link from Heathrow to Reading (WRAtH: Western Rail Access to Heathrow) so there's obviously lots of demand for that route.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, from many places in the south west it's both cheaper and more convenient.

There is a coach from Reading station to Heathrow. If you search the national rail planner for a journey from somewhere in the west (e.g. [Bristol](http://ojp.nationalrail.co.uk/service/timesandfares/Bristol/Heathrow_Terminal_5/today/1300/dep)) to LHR it will generally recommend this as being both quicker and cheaper than taking the train in to London and back. A taxi would presumably be quicker than either as you don't have to wait for the coach's schedule and it doesn't have to stop at other terminals. In terms of price it depends how many people are travelling and how much luggage you have, a quick search for [taxis from Reading](http://www.taxiinreading.co.uk/taxi_minicab_to-or-from-lhr-t5-london-heathrow-terminal-five-and-reading) suggests £33 to £55 for a taxi each way. You can get the train and coach ticket together or book them separately, the [coach ticket price](http://www.railair.com/tickets_prices.php) is apparently £19 single, but you can book an early-bird family return for £35.

Depending on where you are in the south west, going via Woking might be better instead; there is a very similar rail air coach.